# C# WPF MenuStrip Controller

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm Trying to make a MenuBar using WPF in C# by creating a WindowsFormsHost and add a MenuStrip as its child. Note that I add the menu and menu items using the property page of the WindowsFormsHost Controller.

when I am finished, the project builds and runs successfully, yet it shows some errors in the generated "xaml" file and the designer doesn't load the design.

Here's the generated XAML code

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Forms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" x:Class="FrontEnd.AppMainWindow"
    Title="AppMainWindow" Height="351" Width="826">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="menuStripHost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="818">
        <Forms:MenuStrip Visible="True" Name="appMainMenu">
            <Forms:MenuStrip.Items>
                <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="File">
                    <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem ShortcutKeys="Ctrl+N" Text="New Project"/>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem ShortcutKeys="Ctrl+O" Text="Open Project"/>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="Exit"/>
                    </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem>
                <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="View">
                    <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="Configuration Window"/>
                    </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem>
                <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="Help">
                    <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="User Manual"/>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="Help"/>
                    </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem>
            </Forms:MenuStrip.Items>
        </Forms:MenuStrip>
    </WindowsFormsHost>

</Grid></Window>
```

and here's the errors

> Error 2   The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: "String".

The same error appears for all lines that have the TAG "Forms:ToolStripMenuItem"

**UPDATE:**
tried to remove the ShortcutKeys property and the problem still exists (the same error as the above).
Here's the code after modification...

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Forms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" x:Class="FrontEnd.AppMainWindow"
    Title="AppMainWindow" Height="351" Width="826">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="menuStripHost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="818">
        <Forms:MenuStrip Visible="True" Name="appMainMenu">
            <Forms:MenuStrip.Items>
                <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="File">
                    <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="New Project"/>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="Open Project"/>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="Exit"/>
                    </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem>
                <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="View">
                    <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="Configuration Window"/>
                    </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem>
                <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="Help">
                    <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="User Manual"/>
                        <Forms:ToolStripMenuItem Text="Help"/>
                    </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems>
                </Forms:ToolStripMenuItem>
            </Forms:MenuStrip.Items>
        </Forms:MenuStrip>
    </WindowsFormsHost>

</Grid></Window>
```

Comment: Found a good alternative for creating a WindowsFormsHost and create a MenuStrip in it, I used the WPF Menu and MenuItem controllers to implement a menu. 
here's a [link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/menu-control/) introducing them with an example

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your ToolStripMenuItems, you are assigning a string to the ShortcutKeys property: ShortcutKeys="Ctrl+N"... This is supposed to be of type 'Keys' as per the documentation; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.shortcutkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: tried to remove the ShortcutKeys property and the problem still exists...

Comment: are you sure? can you add what you have now to the bottom of your question?

Comment: please have another look at the question as I updated as you requested.